# How to remove mutation on this code Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I managed to write code which does what I need, but I want to make it clean and remove mutation of **realtiveGroups.push()** but don't know how to achieve it.
How to remove mutation from this code?

```
export interface OfferCategory {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

export interface OfferGroup {
  groupId: string;
  dependsOn: OfferCategory;
  name: string;
  rule: Rule;
  products: PosProducts[];
}

function relativesFromSubscription(groups: OfferGroup[], dependingGroups: OfferGroup[]): OfferGroup[] {
    const relativeGroups: OfferGroup[] = [];
    groups.forEach(group => {
      if (dependingGroups.some(dependingGroup => group?.dependsOn?.id === dependingGroup.groupId)) {
        relativeGroups.push(group);
      }
      if (relativeGroups.some(relativeGroup => group?.dependsOn?.id === relativeGroup.groupId)) {
        relativeGroups.push(group);
      }
    });
    return relativeGroups;
  }
```

Comment: Seems like you want [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing everything in one cycle try dividing it into a few:

```
function relativesFromSubscription(groups: OfferGroup[], dependingGroups: OfferGroup[]): OfferGroup[] {
    const groups1 = groups.filter(group => dependingGroups.some(dependingGroup => group?.dependsOn?.id === dependingGroup.groupId));
    const groups2 = groups.filter(group => groups1.some(relGroup=> group?.dependsOn?.id === relGroup.groupId)); 
    return [...groups1, ...groups2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your code and [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const relativeGroups: OfferGroup[] = groups.filter(group => {
    return dependingGroups.some(dependingGroup => group?.dependsOn?.id === dependingGroup.groupId) || relativeGroups.some(relativeGroup => group?.dependsOn?.id === relativeGroup.groupId)
});
```

Or if you want the code to be more readable you can add descriptive variables:

```js
const relativeGroups: OfferGroup[] = groups.filter(group => {
  const hasDependingGroups = dependingGroups.some(dependingGroup => group?.dependsOn?.id === dependingGroup.groupId);

  const hasRelativeGroups = relativeGroups.some(relativeGroup => group?.dependsOn?.id === relativeGroup.groupId)

  return hasDependingGroups || hasRelativeGroups
});
```

Comment: if I use this answer then I get 
Cannot access 'relativeGroups' before initialization.
Because I am trying to access it before it was created.

Comment: my bad, just realized that relativeGroups is created locally. What are you trying to do? just remove the part with`const hasRelativeGroups ` and only return `hasDependingGroups`